# How to colorize with specific color / change color without losing details on the edges

Tags: gimp, image-editing

I have a very simple image that consists of 1 color and text cut out of it (the text is transparent).

[image: example]

I now want to change the colored part to a different color, but on the edges the color is not completely solid as you can see.

When I use **"bucket fill"**, it just fills everything with a solid color.

When I use **"Colorize"** it looks perfect, but then I can't choose a specific hexcode.

When I use **"Colorify"** it looks perfect too and I can choose a hex code, but then it just adds the new color on top of it.

Is there a way to repalce this green with a different specific hex code and keep the details?

Comment: Welcome to Super User Florian! An interesting first question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Change the colour of a layer with an alpha channel or partial transparency

This can be achieved using **channels**, at least in the simple case:

1. In the **Channels** tab (next to **Layers** tab here), right-click on the *alpha* channel
2. Select **channel to selection**
3. Fill with desired colour (I used <kbd>Ctrl+,</kbd> - *Fill with FG colour* in the demo below)

[image: demo]

(Demo of the above on a small sample I created using `GIMP 2.10.6`)

### Note

At step 2, once you've selected the alpha channel; if you zoom in on 'faint' high alpha pixels they may *seem* as though they are not selected, but they are.